# Finding the number of zeros of $f(z) = z^n$ if $|f(z)| < 1 $ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

Suppose $f: \overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, analytic
in $\mathbb{D}$ and satisfies $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|=1$. Find the number of solutions
to the equation $f(z) = z^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. ($\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk).

Some of my own attempts:
Using the Maximum/Minimum Principle, we can split up the the problem in $2$ parts:
Suppose $f$ is constant. It then holds that $z^n = c$ has exactly $n$ zeros because of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Suppose $f$ is not constant. It holds that $f$ has at least one zero 
in $\mathbb{D}$. It of course also holds that $z^n$ has a zero of multiplicity $n$ at the origin. I think I'm supposed to hit with stuff like Rouché's theorem, the Argument Principle or Schwartz lemma, but nothing seems to fit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Rouche's theorem (on wikipedia or elsewhere) and apply it to this situation.

Comment: how is $|z^n| < 1$ on the curve $|z|=1$??

Comment: $|f(z)| <1$ on $|z| = 1$.

Comment: sorry, I misread :(( I thought $f(z) = z^n$

Comment: You should be comparing $z^n$ and $z^n-f(z)$ as I did by connecting them in my answer. You will have to relabel the variables in Rouché`s theorem, since here $f$ is the difference of the functions.

Comment: can't we use constant function for Rouche's theorem? since constant function does not have any zeros inside $|z| < 1$ ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g_t(z)=z^n-tf(z)$ has $n$ solutions inside the unit disk for $t=0$. Due to the continuity of the roots of holomorphic functions, one can continue these $n$ solutions for values of $t\in[0,1]$. Since $|g_t(z)|=1-t|f(z)|>0$ on the unit circle for all these $t$, no root path can cross the unit circle, so no root can escape and no root can enter the unit disk. Thus the number of roots inside the unit disk stays at $n$ until $t=1$.

For a more exact and in its entirety more elementary argument, use the Rouché theorem.

---

Set $a(z)=z^n$ and $b(z)=z^n-f(z)$, then
$$
|a(z)-b(z)|=|f(z)|<1=|a(z)|\le|a(z)|+|b(z)|\quad\text{for}\quad |z|=1
$$
so the assumptions of the [Rouché theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9_theorem) are satisfied in all of its forms and $a(z)$ has the same number of roots inside the unit disk as $b(z)$.

Comment: Rouché's theorem makes it a lot easier and elegant, but I did not make the connection on my own... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You seem to have used the symmetric version of Rouche's theorem, but this one is stronger than Rouche's theorem itself. Is there a way to use the normal Rouche's theorem? (normal Rouche's theorem as in $|a(z)|>|b(z)|$ for all $z \in C$) I have tried with $a(z) = z^n$ and $b(z) = f(z) - z^n$, but can't get that $|z^n-f(z)| < 1 = |z^n|$.

Comment: You need to use the correct functions to compare. Here it is $a$ and $b$, so what you need is $|a(z)-b(z)|<|a(z)|$, which is satisfied due to $|f(z)|<1$.

Comment: Oh so I should be taking $a(z) = z^n$ and $b(z) = f(z)$, and then since $|a(z)| = 1 > f(z)$ on $z \in C$, I get that $z^n$ and $z^n - f(z)$ have the same number of zeros and therefore the number of solutions for $z^n = f(z)$ is equal to $n$.

I realised that I was trying to find then number of zeros of the function $f$, but that was indeed not the question. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. You seem to have a different permutation in the distribution of the terms than I, but the verbal description is correct.